# How to do an insert if not exists with Kotlin Exposed Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, orm, kotlin-exposed

I'm building an expenses tracker app, using Spring Boot with Kotlin to make the API and I'm storing the user data into a Postgresql database. I choosed Exposed ORM to handle all the CRUD operations between Spring and Postgres.

To insert a expense into the database the user can select tags to keep a better organization of their expenses. Expenses and tags are a Many to Many relationship (one expense can have many tags and one tag can have many expenses).

I have the following code to define the tables:

Expense

```kotlin
object ExpenseTable : IntIdTable("expense") {
    val userId: Column<String> = varchar("user_id", 50)
    val concept: Column<String> = varchar("concept", 50)
    val total: Column<Double> = double("total")
    val dateAdded: Column<LocalDateTime> = datetime("date_added")
    val comments: Column<String?> = varchar("comments", 200).nullable()
}

class ExpenseEntity(
    id: EntityID<Int>
) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<ExpenseEntity>(ExpenseTable)

    var userId by ExpenseTable.userId
    var concept by ExpenseTable.concept
    var total by ExpenseTable.total
    var dateAdded by ExpenseTable.dateAdded
    var tags by TagEntity via ExpensesTags
    var comments by ExpenseTable.comments

    fun toExpense() = Expenses(
        id.value,
        userId,
        concept,
        total,
        dateAdded,
        tags.toList().toTags(),
        comments
    )
}
```

Tag

```kotlin
object TagsTable: IntIdTable("tag") {
    val tagName: Column<String> = varchar("tag_name", 25)
    val dateAdded: Column<LocalDateTime> = datetime("date_added")
}

class TagEntity(
    id: EntityID<Int>
): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object: IntEntityClass<TagEntity>(TagsTable)

    var tagName by TagsTable.tagName
    var dateAdded by TagsTable.dateAdded

    fun toTags() = Tags(
        id.value,
        tagName,
        dateAdded
    )
}
```

Many to Many relationship

```kotlin
object ExpensesTags : Table() {
    val expense = reference("expense", ExpenseTable)
    val tag = reference("tag", TagsTable)
    override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(expense, tag, name = "PK_ExpensesTags")
}
```

I want to only have one kind of tag that the user can create, the problem so far is that with the available code from the ORM I cannot find a way to make sure that the tag the user is using exists or not.

So far I have this implementation, but I feel that this is not the best approach since I need to query and check if the tag already exists, and it feels like over killing.

```kotlin
fun insertExpense(expenses: ExpensesPost): Expenses {
    val userIdName = authenticationFacade.userId()
    val tagsPost = expenses.tag

    // We only accept 10 tags max per request
    if (tagsPost.size > MAX_TAG_REQUEST) throw BadRequestException(
        Status.BAD_REQUEST,
        "Only $MAX_TAG_REQUEST tags are allowed"
    )

    var insertedExpense: Expenses? = null
    loggedTransaction {
        // Check if some tags already exists
        tagsPost.forEach { tag ->
            val internTag = tagsCrudTable.find { TagsTable.tagName eq tag.tagName }.firstOrNull()
            // Only insert into the table tags that doesn't exist
            if (internTag == null) {
                tagsCrudTable.new {
                    dateAdded = tag.dateAdded
                    tagName = tag.tagName
                }
            }
        }
        // Get all the tags that come from the request
        val tagsArr = mutableListOf<TagEntity>()
        tagsPost.map {
            val internTag = tagsCrudTable.find {
                TagsTable.tagName eq it.tagName
            }.first()
            tagsArr.add(internTag)
        }
        val expense = expenseCrudTable.new {
            userId = userIdName
            concept = expenses.concept
            total = expenses.total
            dateAdded = expenses.dateAdded
            comments = expenses.comments
        }

        expense.tags = SizedCollection(tagsArr)
        insertedExpense = expense.toExpense()
    }

    return insertedExpense ?: throw EntityNotFoundException(
        status = Status.NO_DATA,
        customMessage = "Something went wrong",
        id = authenticationFacade.userId()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by defining your `tag_name` as unique and using `insertIgnore`:

```kotlin
object TagsTable: IntIdTable("tag") {
    val tagName = varchar("tag_name", 25).uniqueIndex()
    ...
}
```

Then this block:

```kotlin
        tagsPost.forEach { tag ->
            val internTag = tagsCrudTable.find { TagsTable.tagName eq tag.tagName }.firstOrNull()
            // Only insert into the table tags that doesn't exist
            if (internTag == null) {
                tagsCrudTable.new {
                    dateAdded = tag.dateAdded
                    tagName = tag.tagName
                }
            }
        }
```

Can be transformed into this:

```kotlin
tagsPost.forEach { tag ->
    tagsCrudTable.table.insertIgnore {
        dateAdded = tag.dateAdded
        tagName = tag.tagName
    }
}
```

Note that `insertIgnore` is available only on the table, not on the entity.

Also note that this like potentially pollutes the entity:

```kotlin
expense.tags = SizedCollection(tagsArr)
```

You are better setting the tags as you create the entity:

```kotlin
val expense = expenseCrudTable.new {
    ...
    tags = SizedCollection(tagsArr)
}
```